# Hive INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY command output is not separated by a delimiter. Why?

Tags: hadoop, hive

The file that I am loading is separated by ' ' (white space). Below is the file. The file resides in HDFS:-

```
001 000
001 000
002 001
003 002
004 003
005 004
006 005
007 006
008 007
099 007
```

1> I am creating an external table and loading the file by issuing the below command:-

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS graph_edges (src_node_id STRING COMMENT 'Node ID of Source node', dest_node_id STRING COMMENT 'Node ID of Destination node') ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '/user/hadoop/input';
```

2> After this, I am simply inserting the table in another file by issuing the below command:-

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/user/hadoop/output' SELECT * FROM graph_edges;
```

3> Now, when I cat the file, the fields are not separated by any delimiter:-

```
hadoop dfs -cat /user/hadoop/output/000000_0
```

Output:-

```
001000
001000
002001
003002
004003
005004
006005
007006
008007
099007
```

Can somebody please help me out? Why is the delimiter being removed and how to delimit the output file?

In the CREATE TABLE command I tried `DELIMITED BY '\t'` but then I am getting unnecessary NULL column.

Any pointers help much appreciated. I am using Hive 0.9.0 version.

Comment: Are you sure there is no delimiter in the output directory? By default, Hive uses '\1' for the field delimiter, so you should try `hadoop dfs -cat "/user/hadoop/output/*" | tr '\001' ' '

Comment: Be sure to see the answer from @garren -- current versions of Hive allow  `INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY...ROW FORMAT` and `INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY...STORED AS`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that HIVE does not allow you to specify the output delimiter - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-634

The solution is to create external table for output (with delimiter specification) and insert overwrite table instead of directory.

--

Assuming that you have /user/hadoop/input/graph_edges.csv in HDFS,

```
hive> create external table graph_edges (src string, dest string) 
    > row format delimited 
    > fields terminated by ' ' 
    > lines terminated by '\n' 
    > stored as textfile location '/user/hadoop/input';

hive> select * from graph_edges;
OK
001 000
001 000
002 001
003 002
004 003
005 004
006 005
007 006
008 007
099 007

hive> create external table graph_out (src string, dest string) 
    > row format delimited 
    > fields terminated by ' ' 
    > lines terminated by '\n' 
    > stored as textfile location '/user/hadoop/output';

hive> insert into table graph_out select * from graph_edges;
hive> select * from graph_out;
OK
001 000
001 000
002 001
003 002
004 003
005 004
006 005
007 006
008 007
099 007

[user@box] hadoop fs -get /user/hadoop/output/000000_0 .
```

Comes back as above, with spaces.

Comment: I created a new **non external** table and then inserted the data from external table to internal table to HDFS file. But still the same result, there is no delimiter at all. Even if Hive does not allow to specify output delimiter it MUST delimit the output by some delimiter.

Comment: Ok, assuming that you have /user/hadoop/input/graph_edges.csv in HDFS,

Comment: Yes, graph_edges file is in HDFS. I will edit my question to put this detail. Also, please note that `graph_edges` is not a comma separated file, it is white space separated file.

Comment: This worked exactly. Thank you very much. So the point I learnt is that in Hive, to preserve formatting/delimiters, an external table should always be written to another external table though somehow in my opinion I find this restriction to be a bug.

Comment: Yep, there is a request out to be able to specify formatting for insert overwrite. You're welcome!

Answer (score 17):

While the question is over 2 years old and the top answer was correct at the time, it is now possible to tell Hive to write delimited data to a directory.

Here is an example of outputting the data with the traditional ^A separator:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/output/data_delimited'
SELECT *
FROM data_schema.data_table
```

And now with tab delimiters:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/output/data_delimited'
row format delimited 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
SELECT *
FROM data_schema.data_table
```

Comment: [from here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Writingdataintothefilesystemfromqueries): "custom separators are only supported for LOCAL writes in Hive versions 0.11.0 to 1.1.0 – this bug is fixed in version 1.2.0 (see HIVE-5672)"

Answer (score 11):

I think using the concat_ws function you can achieve your output;

> INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/user/hadoop/output'  SELECT
>   concat_ws(',', col1, col2) FROM graph_edges;

here i have chosen comma as the column delimiter

Answer (score 4):

I have some different voice.

Indeed, Hive does not support custom delimiter.

But when you use `INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY`, there are delimiters in your lines. The delimiter is `'\1'`.

You can use `hadoop dfs -cat $file | head -1 | xxd` to find it out or get the file from HDFS to local machine and open it with vim. There will be some char like '^A' in your vim which is the delimiter.

Back to the question, You can use a simple way to solve it.

1. Still use `INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/user/hadoop/output'` to generate `/user/hadoop/output`;
2. Create external table whose fields delimited by `'\1'`:

   ```
   create external table graph_out (src string, dest string) 
   row format delimited 
   fields terminated by '\1' 
   lines terminated by '\n' 
   stored as textfile location '/user/hadoop/output';
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You can provide delimiter when writing to directories

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/user/hadoop/output'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY
SELECT * FROM graph_edges;
```

This should work for you.

Comment: I am getting error: FAILED: ParseException line 2:0 cannot recognize input near 'ROW' 'FORMAT' 'DELIMITED' in select clause

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue where the output of the hive query results should be pipe delimited..
Running this sed command you can replace: `^A to |`

`sed 's#\x01#|#g' test.log > piped_test.log`

Answer (score 0):

The default separator is **"^A"**. In python language, it is **"\x01"**.

When I want to change the delimiter, I use SQL like:

SELECT col1, delimiter, col2, delimiter, col3, ...,
FROM table

Then, regard ***delimiter+"^A"*** as a new delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that hive actually is writing a contol-A as the delimeter, but when you do a cat to the screen it is not showing up to your eye.

Instead try bringing up the file in vi or head the file if you only want to see a little of it, and vi the result:

hadoop dfs -cat /user/hadoop/output/000000_0 | head > my_local_file.txt

vi my_local_file.txt

You should be able to see the ^A characters in there.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a better solution I suppose though its a round about way of achieving.

INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/user/hadoop/output' SELECT src_node_id,' ',dest_node_id FROM graph_edges;

Answer (score 0):

you can use this parameter **"row format delimited fields terminated by '|'"** for example in your case should be

INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/user/hadoop/output' row format delimited fields terminated by '|' SELECT * FROM graph_edges;