# Can I change the default line delimiter of Hive?

Tags: hive, delimiter

I can change the default field delimiter of hive, but I cannot find a way to change the default line delimiter, I have many files whose data's line delimiter is `'\u0002'`, and if I rewriting the InputFormat of hive by overriding `next()` function:

```
@Override
        public boolean next(LongWritable key, Text value) throws IOException {
            while (reader.next(key, text)) {                
                String strReplace = text.toString().toLowerCase()
                        .replaceAll("\u0002", "\n");
                Text txtReplace = new Text();
                txtReplace.set(strReplace);
                value.set(txtReplace.getBytes(), 0, txtReplace.getLength());
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

But it didn't work, so if there have another ways?

Comment: Information on setting hive's delimiter can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459790/hive-insert-overwrite-directory-command-output-is-not-separated-by-a-delimiter